# is there a way to start a Minecraft server through port forwarding?

Tags: networking, router, minecraft, portforwarding

I'm trying to set up a modded minecraft server, minecraft is 1.12.2, sevtech ages is the pack.

I've tried to play the game through hamachi, but it doesn't have the bandwidth for us to play comfortably.

Now I'm trying to forward port 25565, but whatever I do, it does not seem to work. My router is keenetic Extra II and my keeneticOS version is 3.5.4. Also, my Windows 10 version is 10.0.19041.

I've tried to create a rule to forward the 25565 port, but if I enable it, the port is still closed. I don't really know much about networking, so that is the only thing I've tried.

Comment: Make sure to open the port on the Windows firewall as well as your router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout ngrok. You can create a tunnel using ngrok then send the ip to your friends and they can join it using the tunnel. It is quite easy.